# Change color of different paths in SVGs / same SVG multiple times in page

Tags: css, svg

On a page where a map (SVG) is occuring several times I tried not to put the whole map-SVG in each div. I want to highlight a different state of the country in the different places. Can I do that with CSS? Instead of putting the whole map here, I used just these four squares. For example in div1 I want the upper left square in red, in div2 the upper right etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>SVGs</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="karte.css" /> -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <style>
      :root {
        --colorSQ1: red;
        --colorSQ2: green;
        --colorSQ3: blue;
        --colorSQ4: yellow;
      }
    </style>
    <div style="display: none">
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      >
        <symbol viewBox="0 0 200 200" id="4squares" style="fill: lightblue">
          <g class="sq1">
            <rect id="sq-1" width="50" height="50" x="0" y="0" />
          </g>
          <g class="sq2">
            <rect id="sq-2" width="50" height="50" x="50" y="0" />
          </g>
          <g class="sq3">
            <rect id="sq-3" width="50" height="50" x="0" y="50" />
          </g>
          <g class="sq4">
            <rect id="sq-4" width="50" height="50" x="50" y="50" />
          </g>
        </symbol>
      </svg>
    </div>

    <section class="d-karte">
      <div class="div1" id="div1">
        <h4>squares I</h4>
        <div class="dkarte-box">
          <span
            ><svg class="dkarte">
              <use xlink:href="#4squares"></use></svg
          ></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="div2">
        <h4>squares II</h4>
        <div class="dkarte-box">
          <span
            ><svg class="dkarte">
              <use xlink:href="#4squares"></use></svg
          ></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="div3">
        <h4>squares III</h4>
        <div class="dkarte-box">
          <span
            ><svg class="dkarte">
              <use xlink:href="#4squares"></use></svg
          ></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="div4">
        <h4>squares IV</h4>
        <div class="dkarte-box">
          <span
            ><svg class="dkarte">
              <use xlink:href="#4squares"></use></svg
          ></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried "reaching" each square in CSS with for example .div1.dkarte-box.dkarte.sq1 and other combinations...

Comment: You need a space between the .div1 and the .sq1.

Comment: ie. Every one (or more) nested HTML levels need to be separated with a space. Learn CSS selectors with: https://flukeout.github.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign a **css variable** to each rectangle's fill style

```
<svg>
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 200 200" id="4squares">
      <rect id="sq-1" width="50" height="50" x="0" y="0" style="fill:var(--colorSQ1)" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

or as a CSS rule

```
#sq-1 {
  fill: var(--colorSQ1);
}

.div1 svg {
  --colorSQ1: orange;
}
```

and redefine this variable for different instances like so:

```
  <svg class="dkarte" style="--colorSQ1: #ccc;">
    <use xlink:href="#4squares" />
  </svg>
```

```css
#sq-2 {
  fill: var(--colorSQ2);
}

#sq-3 {
  fill: var(--colorSQ3);
}

#sq-4 {
  fill: var(--colorSQ4);
}

:root{
  --colorSQ1: #111;
  --colorSQ2: #222;
  --colorSQ3: #333;
  --colorSQ4: #444;
}



.div2 svg {
  --colorSQ1: orange;
}

.div3 svg {
  --colorSQ2: orange;
}

.div4 svg {
  --colorSQ3: orange;
}
```

```html
  <div style="display: none">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" fill="red">
      <symbol viewBox="0 0 200 200" id="4squares">
        <g class="sq1">
          <rect id="sq-1" width="50" height="50" x="0" y="0" style="fill: var(--colorSQ1)" />
        </g>
        <g class="sq2">
          <rect id="sq-2" width="50" height="50" x="50" y="0" />
        </g>
        <g class="sq3">
          <rect id="sq-3" width="50" height="50" x="0" y="50" />
        </g>
        <g class="sq4">
          <rect id="sq-4" width="50" height="50" x="50" y="50" />
        </g>
      </symbol>
    </svg>
  </div>

  <section class="d-karte">
    <div class="div1" id="div1">
      <h4>squares I</h4>
      <div class="dkarte-box">
        <span>
          <svg class="dkarte" style=" --colorSQ4: orange;" >
            <use xlink:href="#4squares" />
          </svg>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
      <h4>squares II</h4>
      <div class="dkarte-box">
        <span>
          <svg class="dkarte">
            <use xlink:href="#4squares" />
          </svg>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
      <h4>squares III</h4>
      <div class="dkarte-box">
        <span>
          <svg class="dkarte">
            <use xlink:href="#4squares" />
          </svg></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div4">
      <h4>squares IV</h4>
      <div class="dkarte-box">
        <span>
          <svg class="dkarte">
            <use xlink:href="#4squares" />
          </svg>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

However this approach will only work for static color changes.
You can't access `<symbol>` children via css - for instance change colors when hovering a particular rect.